# I am trying to post jsonArray to php but getting error org.json.JsonArray cannot be converted

Tags: json, post, http-post

I am trying to post jsonArray to php server but getting Error while posting org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSON Object

Please let me know the issue

JSONArray jArr=SubstationDb.getResults();
e
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject(jArr.toString());

```
        JSONArray data = postDataParams.getJSONArray("");
        for(int i=0;i<=jArr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

           postDataParams.putOpt("did",c.getString("did"));
            postDataParams.put("bid",c.getString("bid"));
            postDataParams.put("vid", c.getString("vid"));
            postDataParams.put("substn_name", c.getString("substn_name"));
            postDataParams.put("sub_height", c.getString("sub_height"));
            postDataParams.put("latitude", c.getString("latitude"));
            postDataParams.put("longitude", c.getString("longitude"));
            postDataParams.put("serial_number", c.getString("serial_number"));
            postDataParams.put("nickname", c.getString("nickname"));
            postDataParams.put("substn_pic", c.getString("substn_pic"));
            postDataParams.put("substn_status", c.getString("substn_status"));
            postDataParams.put("uploadedtime", c.getString("uploadedtime"));
            postDataParams.put("sid", c.getString("sid"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray postDataParams = new JSONArray();
```

First create a postDataParams array and then push it to JSONObject and send it to backend.

Comment: Thanks i already solved it in different way and its working fine.